# Proving inequality of addition and multiplication

Tags: inequality

Which approach can be used to proof the inequality of the following equation?

$$ax^2 + cy^2 = -2bxy.$$

We only know that $a > 0$ and $c > 0$ as well as:

$$ac - b^2 > 0.$$

Therefore $b$ can be $< 0$, $= 0$ and $> 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The inequality of the following equation" has no clear meaning. We will show that under the given conditions on $a$, $b$, and $c$, the only solution of our equation is the trivial $x=y=0$.

The equation holds $ax^2+cy^2=-2bxy$ holds for particular $x$ and $y$ if and only if $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2=0$. And this holds if and only if 
$$a^2x^2+2abxy+acy^2=0.$$
(We multiplied through by $a$.)

Note that 
$$a^2x^2+2abxy+acy^2=(ax+by)^2+(ac-b^2)y^2.$$
(We completed the square,)

Since any square is non-negative, we have  $(ax+by)^2\ge 0$.

Since $ac-b^2\gt 0$, we have  $(ac-b^2)y^2\ge 0$.

So the only way that $(ax+by)^2+(ac-b^2)y^2$ can be equal to $0$ is if both terms are equal to $0$. Setting $(ac-b^2)y^2=0$, we conclude that $y=0$. Then from $(ax+by)^2=0$ we conclude that $x=0$.

So under our conditions on $a$, $b$, and $c$, the only real solution of the equation $ax^2+cy^2=-2bxy$ is $x=y=0$.